# Submit button with php variable

Tags: php, forms, submit

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="'.$pTest.'" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST[''.$pTest.'']))
{echo 'something'
;}
?>
```

This doesn't work if I use variable as the name of the submit button. Please some help!

Comment: Why the empty strings around the variable in the $_POST check? It's not the problem, but it's useless.

Comment: That syntax is incorrect. Have a look at how to insert a PHP variable inside HTML. Just one of the many examples: [php variable in html no other way then: `<?php echo $var; ?>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150238/php-variable-in-html-no-other-way-then-php-echo-var)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $pTest; ?>" value="submit" id="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is doing nothing. Just `echo` your `<input>` name and catch it whith php:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $pTest ?>" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST[$pTest])) {

        echo 'something'

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add value to the variable first..**

```
<?php  $pTest = 'sks'; ?>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" method="post" name="<?php echo $pTest; ?>" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST[$pTest]))
{
    echo '<script>alert("something");</script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just replace your quotes with double quotes :

```
if(isset($_POST["'.$pTest.'"]))
{
    echo 'something'
;}
```

Or name your input with a PHP variable :

```
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $pTest; ?>" value="submit" id="submit"/>
```

Comment: You honestly believe that he wants to name the submit button: `'.$pTest.'`?

Comment: Nope, but if he wants, he can :)

Comment: He can but it doesn't mean he should. Encouraging best practices while answering a question is much more valuable than blindly answering a question just for the sake of a few rep points.

Comment: You're right, that's why I edited my post with a real answer ;)