# Display <ul> from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a script that i use my database to show the menu of a page. But i ran into a problem...

The script on my website. : [Click here](http://beta.martijnmelchers.nl/#)

## Problem

So i have this code

**UPDATED CODE AND ADDED LINK**

```
                                <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Heroic Features - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/heroic-features.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<?php
$db = new mysqli('xxxxxxxxxxx');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

if($_GET['action'] == '')
            {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM li_psp";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo "                    <li>
                        <a href='{$row['li_href']}'>{$row['li_label']}</a>
                        </li>";



}

}   

                        ?>

<?php
$db = new mysqli('xxxxxxxxxxx');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

if($_GET['action'] == '')
            {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ul_psp";
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<li class='dropdown'>
              <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>{$row['ul_name']} <b class='caret'></b></a>
              <ul class='dropdown-menu'>";

if($_GET['action'] == '')
            {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ul_data_psp WHERE belong_to = {$row['ul_name']}";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo "                    <li>
                        <a href='{$row['ul_data_href']}'>{$row['ul_data_label']}</a>
                        </li>";




echo "</ul>
            </li>";



}

}   
}
}
                        ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

But for some reason it does not work. I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/u799303375/public_html/beta/include/menu.php on line 98`

## What have i tried?

I tried changing all the " to ' but it didn't work, i need help fixing this code, if you have any other things i can do better please tell it! Thanks!

Comment: Look at the color highlighting in your pasted code above. You have mis-placed `"` and whatnot on your echo. e.g. your first `echo` never terminates the string until it's waaaay too late.

Comment: you didn't close your `echo`

Comment: You haven't told us what line 98 is, but my guess is in your while loop, just about the third line where you forget a semi-colon. You likely have many other syntax errors too.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You have also many opening php Tags `<?php`. You also don't to open your database connection for each query. Or are that to seperate files? Please format your code so that is more readable.

Comment: As a code-readability recommendation, write as much of your html normally as you can, and use this method to access php variables. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2150255/1585160

Comment: @MarcB Here are 2 links, how it shows it and the database code. http://beta.martijnmelchers.nl/ - How the code ouputs it. http://beta.martijnmelchers.nl/php.txt - The code itself

Comment: @tadman Watch this comment, does it help? ^

Comment: @Eeji Watch the comment @marcb!

Comment: @MartijnMelchers posted at the same time :D

Comment: @Eeji How do you mean haha?

Comment: Mine and marcb's comments :)

Comment: Can you help me to check the post added some links to it and stuff :) @Eeji

Comment: @MartijnMelchers That code looks dangerously insecure. It's not even clear what the problem is here. If you have syntax errors, fix them.

Answer (score -1):

You have malformed quotationmarks. Put variables not directly into strings, concat them with a `.`:

```
echo '<li><a href=' . $row['ul_data_href'] . '>' . $row['ul_data_label'] . '</a></li>'
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with inlining strings, it's completely allowed.

Comment: "put variables not directly into strings"? That's pathetically dumb advice. There is **NO** reason to suggest that. OP is using the proper `{}` extended syntax, any decent code editor will highlight the variables properly anyways. And switching to this concat format just adds **MORE** quote characters that might get misbalacned.

Comment: @MarcB It's allowed yes... but the advice is not dumb at all. It makes things way easier to read, putting every part starting with a dot on a new line. All companies I've been working for do it this way, for a good reason. Of course it is allowed to use messy style, but it ends up with wrong quotes too often.