# Insert PHP Integer Variable into HTML

Tags: php, html, integer

I have a PHP code that draws my subscriber count from my YouTube channel and sets it as an integer variable, `$subs`. I need to use the variable `$subs` in this piece of HTML code.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="col-md-6 bottommargin-sm">
    <div class="counter counter-small"><span data-from="100" data-to="$subs" data-refresh-interval="50" data-speed="2000" data-comma="true"></span></div>
        <h5 class="nobottommargin">Subs</h5>
</div>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    function retrieveContent($url){
        $file = fopen($url,"rb");

        if (!$file) return "";
        while (feof ($file)===false) {
            $line = fgets ($file, 1024);
            $salida .= $line;
        }

        fclose($file);
        return $salida;
    }
        {
            $content = retrieveContent("youtube.com/user/geekawhat/about"); $start = strpos($content,'<span class="about-stat"><b>');
            $end = strpos($content,'</b>',$start+1);
            $output = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);
            $subs = (int)$output;
            echo "$output";
         }
?>
```

It is a counter, and I want it to count to whatever that variable equals. I have placed the variable in the data-to field, which informs the counter what to count upto - how do I get this to work? (**This does work btw with a number inserted into the data-to field**)

Comment: <?php echo $subs; ?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php variable in html no other way then: <?php echo $var; ?>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150238/php-variable-in-html-no-other-way-then-php-echo-var)

Comment: I question the quality of your PHP code, it looks like it would not run or would return at error?

Comment: How will the server know what to do of $subs. It will parse $subs are plain html. To tell the server that it is php code, wrap it in <?php and ?>. So <?php echo $subs; ?> or <?= $subs ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply echo it out:

`data-to="<?php echo $subs; ?>"`

or if you have PHP short tags enabled:

`data-to="<?= $subs ?>"`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: It just shows NaN, I presume I would also lose the animated number count up if it worked anyway?

Comment: `NaN` is not something PHP would output. That sounds like JavaScript is interfering.

Comment: yes NaN it is like JavaScript or Jquery.

Comment: oh right, can javascript or jquery not read a php integer variable?

Comment: Sure it can. How are you reading the value back? jquery's `.data('to')` would automatically convert it to an integer when it's read. On the other hand, if you're using `.attr('data-to')`, it would be read as a string, and you may need to use `parseInt()` on the value first if you want to use it as an integer. Suggest looking at the source code first to see if PHP has inserted the intended value.

Answer (score 0):

You can just [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) it:

> Output one or more strings

```
data-to="<?php echo $subs ?>"
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`print()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php):

> Output a string

```
data-to="<?php print $subs ?>"
```

Comment: It just shows the counter count from 50 to 0 (is it set to start at 0) - showing it cant read the variable value, I presume I would also lose the animated number count up if it worked anyway?

Comment: @JamesCousins Can you upload more code, problem doesn't seem to be in by your current code

Comment: This is the PHP retrieving the sub count:                                               <?php
set_time_limit(0);

function retrieveContent($url){
$file = fopen($url,"rb");
if (!$file)
    return "";
while (feof ($file)===false) {
    $line = fgets ($file, 1024);
    $salida .= $line;
}
fclose($file);
return $salida;
}

{
$content = retrieveContent("https://www.youtube.com/user/geekawhat/about");
$start = strpos($content,'<span class="about-stat"><b>');
$end = strpos($content,'</b>',$start+1);
$output = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);

$subs = (int)$output;

echo "$output";
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

use php tag and echo where you want

```
<div class="col-md-6 bottommargin-sm">
    <div class="counter counter-small">
    <span data-from="100" data-to="<?php echo $subs; ?>" data-refresh-interval="50" data-speed="2000" data-comma="true"></span>
</div>
<h5 class="nobottommargin">Subs</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't count up, it just shows it as a solid value, implying it cannot read it as an integer

Comment: if you are using javascript or jquery then problem in there so post these too if you will.