# Using HTML and PHP together

Tags: php, html, session

I would like to use HTML and PHP together. However it's not working.

I would like to have something like: Logged in as *username*

```
echo "<ul> <li>Logged in as</li> </ul>";
```

However I want to add $_SESSION['username'] to it within the listed object.

What is the best way to do this?

Cheers!

Comment: "not working" is not a sufficient problem description. Enable error reporting, then showcase the actual attempt. See the PHP manual on (curly) string interpolation.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150238/php-variable-in-html-no-other-way-then-php-echo-var

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your problem, but have you tried:

```
echo "<ul> <li>Logged in as ".$_SESSION['username']."</li> </ul>";
```

Comment: @user115195 glad I was able to help. :) please mark my answer as the correct answer to your question