# How to declare a PHP variable and pass it into AJAX url?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When i call `/comment.php` it returns data that i've requested. where **post_id** is fixed.

**/comment.php**

```
 "ajax":
{
 "url": "http://localhost/fb-callback.php?post_id=12345_67890",
   "type" : "GET",
"dataSrc":  function (response) { 
                // console.log(response);
                            if(response.whaterver == 0){
                               //DO YOUR THING HERE
                            }
                            //return back the response
                            return response; 
                        },
```

Instead of fixed id (**12345_67890**), i wanna declare a php variable there, 
something like this ::-

```
<?php
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
?>

 "ajax":
{
 "url": "http://localhost/fb-callback.php?post_id="+"&uid",
"type" : "GET",
 ................
```

so that when i'll call url `/comment.php?uid=12345_67890**` it'll return results. But it seems it doesn't work that way. 
HOW CAN I DO THAT Or is there other way to make this call ?

Here is the Full code ::: https://pastebin.com/iy3htv63

Comment: `"url": "http://localhost/fb-callback.php?post_id=<?= $uid ?>",` see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150238/php-variable-in-html-no-other-way-than-php-echo-var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can `echo` it on the ajax url. try this

```
 <?php
  $uid = $_GET['uid'];
?>

 "ajax":
{
 "url": "http://localhost/fb-callback.php?post_id=<?php echo $uid; ?>",
 "type" : "GET",
 ................
```

Comment: thanks, thats really helps me a lot... appreciate it :)

Comment: This is a bad coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
?>
var uid = <?php echo $uid; ?>;
 "ajax":
{
 "url": "http://localhost/fb-callback.php?post_id="+uid,
"type" : "GET",
 ................
```